# Query not updated with new value using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()?

Tags: cursor, arcpy

What is wrong with this code?

```
query='"depth">1700 AND "depth"<1750'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_layer,"depth",query)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

My query is not updated with the new value.

Comment: getting error RuntimeError: create cursor has failed

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new use please take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Here your question body is "code only" with no indication of what it is supposed to do, and an error message only revealed in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the [AddFieldDelimiters](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//018v0000006p000000) function. This allows you to enter a field name and a data source, and the field delimiters are automatically added.

```
field = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(out_layer, "depth")
query = """{0} > 1700 AND {0} < 1750""".format(field)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(out_layer, "depth", query) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = 0
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

This is assuming `out_layer` is a valid layer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need double quotes around the field names. If you depth field is numeric, use this:

```
query = '''depth > 1700 AND depth < 1750'''
```

Also, enclosing the query with triple quotes is a good way to make sure the quotes delimiting the query won't be matched with the quotes delimiting field values within the query.